# Azure Snapshot without losing IP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, snapshot

I have several VMs running, but sometimes i have to clone them to make a sandbox server on where i can run trials and procedures, the problem is that everytime i make an image the VM stops and reboots loosing its public IP, forcing me to manually change all the IPs on the client computers, i know that the domain name solves this, but unfortunatelly i can only enter the numeric IP on the clients

Is there a way to take a SnapShot from an Azure VM without losing the assigned public IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reserve the ip using powershell or preview portal. Unfortunately, you can only reserve ip address during VM creation. You will have to delete the cloud service and recreate it using a reserved ip. That way you won't lose it after restart or shutdown.

[Reserved Public IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/)

**My blog post about this**

http://www.azurekb.com.br/reserve-ip-address-to-an-existing-virtual-machine/

In case you also need to keep the internal private IP address, you can easily use the preview portal to configure static ip on existing VMs or via powershell:

[Set a Static Internal IP Address for a VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/)

Answer (score 0):

Add another VM in the Hosted Service while you are doing the Snapshot. The Hosted Service (and hence the VIP) won't be deleted if there is at least one VM in it.

After you are done with the snapshot, delete the temporary VM.